# PhpStorm 9/10 freezes on Mac on breakpoint hit

Tags: macos, phpstorm

I am really really tired and confused but not able to resolve this issue.

My PhpStorm ( v9 and v10 ) freezes on `breakpoint` hit.

I am using `MAC 10`. I have tried disabling 'git' and 'cvs' plugin yet no affect.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What language is that: php or js?

Comment: disable the maximum of plugins and reactivate those one by one.

Comment: @LazyOne : it is for php ..

Comment: Anything interesting in idea.log file? Otherwise no clue, really.